# Backbone.js filter on any value in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a search/filter field that I would like to be able to filter on any value of the collection. The data I have is as follows:

```
 exports.administrators = [
{
  id: 1,
  firstName: "User1",
  lastName: "Tester",
  phone: "781-000-0000",
  email: "user1.tester@email.com",
  privileges: "view-only"
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Mickey",
  lastName: "Mouse",
  phone: "781-123-4567",
  email: "mickey.mouse@disney.com",
  privileges: "all"
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: "Snow",
  lastName: "White",
  phone: "781-890-1234",
  email: "snow.white@disney.com",
  privileges: "all"
}, {
  id: 4,
  firstName: "Anakin",
  lastName: "Skywalker",
  phone: "888-874-9084",
  email: "anakin.skywalker@deathstar.com",
  privileges: "view-only"
}, {
  id: 5,
  firstName: "Obi-one",
  lastName: "Kenobi",
  phone: "908-765-5432",
  email: "obi.kenobi@jedi.com",
  privileges: "all"
}, {
  id: 6,
  firstName: "Master",
  lastName: "Yoda",
  phone: "876-654-2134",
  email: "yoda@jedi.com",
  privileges: "view-only"
}, {
  id: 7,
  firstName: "Han",
  lastName: "Solo",
  phone: "781-456-3209",
  email: "han.solo@gmail.com",
  privileges: "all"
}, {
  id: 8,
  firstName: "Neo",
  lastName: "TheOne",
  phone: "781-000-0000",
  email: "neo@matrix.com",
  privileges: "all"
}];
```

The View will fire an event based on the keyup event:

```
AdministratorView.prototype.events = {
  'click .sub-content th.sort, .sub-content th.sort-up, .sub-content th.sort-down': 'sortTable',
  'click .light-btn': 'showAdd',
  'keyup #filter-find': 'filterAdministrators'
};
```

I have also abstracted the function that I want to perform the filtering:

```
  App.Utils.filterCollection = function(collection, filterValue) {
if (filterValue !== "") {
  return _.filter(collection.models, function(data) {
    var values;
    values = _.values(data.attributes);
    _.each(values, function(value) {
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        value = value.toString();
      }
      return value.indexOf(filterValue) > 0;
    });
  });
}
```

};

The problem I have is:

1. The filterCollection function is returning undefined
2. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Cheers,

Kianosh

Updated function:

I have updated the function with some input from @dbaseman

```
  App.Utils.filterCollection = function(collection, filterValue) {
var filteredCollection;
if (filterValue === "") {
  [];
}
return filteredCollection = collection.filter(function(data) {
  return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
    value = !isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value;
    return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
  });
});
```

};

However I am still getting an empty (or undefined) value from the function. I am stomped!!

Update #2
Found a partial solution. Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kianoshp/YWSSp/. It filters correctly, however when I blank out the filter field I expect the original data set to be displayed. However now I get a blank table. Working on solution but any help/hint would be helpful.

Update #3
Final solution is here in the jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/kianoshp/YWSSp/77/ thanks to @dbaseman

Comment: These three pieces of code aren't connected and you don't explain how you connect them. Do you create a collection from the data you shown? What collection? Is the `events` property related to a view that renders that collection? What's up with `App.Utils`? Please give more details about how this code is tied together so we might get better idea what is not working properly.

Comment: What should `App.Utils.filterCollection` do? Maybe you could add an example of some expected output.

Comment: @gryzzly I did not want to fill the screen with all the code. The data is fetched in a collection which is consumed in a view (AdministratorsView). The App.Utils.filterCollection is a global function which I will be able to pass any collection and filter value and be able to return a filtered collection that matches any value in the given collection. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @rdiazv the purpose of the App.Utils.filterCollection is that I would like to be able pass any value and the collection will be filtered based on that value. For example, if I pass 'Mouse' to the above data, the collection returned will return a collection containing only 'Mickey Mouse'. Also if I pass in 'jedi.com', the collection will be filtered and I will get all the users with en email of 'jedi.com'. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the answer McGarnagle provided and added some improvements. The below code allows you to search inside Models that have properties consisting of objects.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.filterValues = function(filterValue) {
if (filterValue === ""){
    return this.models;
}

function collectionFilter(data) {
    if(data.toJSON){
        data = data.toJSON();
    }

    return _.some(_.values(data), function(value) {
        if(_.isObject(value)){
            return collectionFilter(value);
        }

        if (_.isNumber(value)){
            value = value.toString();
        }

        if (_.isString(value)){
            value = value.toLowerCase();

            return value.indexOf(filterValue) !== -1;
        }

        return false;
    });
}

return this.filter(collectionFilter);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a more elegant way, except for minor improvements:

1. Backbone collections proxy to Underscore.JS methods, so you can use `collection.filter`
2. Yould also use `_.some` to check if any value matches

As far as problems, there are two as far as I could tell:

1. You're calling `_.values` on a Backbone model (that's what `filter` returns when called on a Backbone collection).  You have to call filter on the JSON representation, using `model.toJSON()`.
2. You're checking if the value is a *number*, but then calling `indexOf` on the value.  I think you meant to check if it's a *string* (`typeof value == 'string').

Here's the modified function ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZWu4/8/)).

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.filterValues = function(filterValue) {
    if (filterValue == "") return [];
    return this.filter(function(data) {
        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
           if (_.isNumber(value)) value = value.toString();
           if (_.isString(value)) return value.indexOf(filterValue) != -1;
           return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. One small issue, I am not sure if `_.some` will work because I do not want the iterator to stop traversing if any value is true. I think `_.contains` might work better. In regards to the checking a value is a number, I am doing that so that if it is a number; I will convert it to a string and then evaluate it. Cheers.

Comment: @Kianosh ah right, I missed the part about converting the number to a string.  Why would you want to stop traversing?  If an attribute value matches -- then that model should always return *true* to the filter iterator ... right?

Comment: you are right; I do want to use `_.some`. I have updated the function above. I checked the function and the it is returning true when it should; however the return value is always empty or undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Kianosh I'm not sure -- I plugged your updated function in to the Fiddle and it seems to be working.  Which browser are you on?

Comment: @Kianosh saw your update -- the filter changes the Backbone collection to a JSON array, so you have to do the same for the empty filter case: `return collection.toJSON()`.  http://jsfiddle.net/U8qGx/

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for your help. I would up vote your answer but I do not have the street cred (according to stack overflow) yet.

Comment: IMP! Just leaving a note for the people that might just scroll down. Final answer is in question's jsfiddle link